# Deserializing JSON to C# Class

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, jsonconvert

I'm calling an API that returns JSON data as follows (the array has around 500 items):

```
[
    [
        1571702400000,
        "8197.28000000",
        "8297.99000000",
        "8000.00000000",
        "8020.00000000",
        "34651.82866300",
        1571788799999,
        "283535483.41051363",
        384699,
        "16767.03682400",
        "137253195.95826291",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1614816000000,
        "50349.37000000",
        "51773.88000000",
        "49010.10000000",
        "49653.85000000",
        "25551.11905400",
        1614902399999,
        "1280981565.05072601",
        731056,
        "12197.45497900",
        "611820740.21554123",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to parse this data using **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)**.

Both attempts I've tried (see below) produce the following error:

**Error Message**

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '...+CandleSticks' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

**Attempt #1:**

```
public class CandleStick
{
    public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; } 
}
...
CandleStick myCandles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CandleStick>(result);
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
public class CandleStick
{
    public long openTime { get; set; }
    public string open { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string close { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public long closeTime { get; set; }
    public string quoteAssetVolume { get; set; }
    public int numberOfTrades { get; set; }
    public string takerBuyBaseAssetVolume { get; set; }
    public string takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume { get; set; }
    public string ignore { get; set; }
}
...
List<CandleStick> myCandles = (List<CandleStick>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(List<CandleStick>));
```

How should I parse the JSON data correctly into a C# class?

**EDIT - UPDATE**

I can now deserialize the "unhelpful" JSON as follows:

```
var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(result);
            IEnumerable<CandleStick> candles = from values in arrays
                               select new CandleStick
                               {
                                   openTime = Convert.ToInt64(values[0]),
                                   open = Convert.ToString(values[1]),
                                   high = Convert.ToString(values[2]),
                                   low = Convert.ToString(values[3]),
                                   close = Convert.ToString(values[4]),
                                   volume = Convert.ToString(values[5]),
                                   closeTime = Convert.ToInt64(values[6]),
                                   quoteAssetVolume = Convert.ToString(values[7]),
                                   numberOfTrades = Convert.ToInt32(values[8]),
                                   takerBuyBaseAssetVolume = Convert.ToString(values[9]),
                                   takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = Convert.ToString(values[10]),
                                   ignore = Convert.ToString(values[11])
                               };

CandleStick cd = candles.ElementAt(0);
```

When I try to reference the elements of candles, I get an error msg saying that the expected string was not in the correct format.

Silly me! If I think about it more carefully the error message makes sense. My array was not converting one of the elements correctly. Now I can reference the data as expected - ElementAt(x) .ToList(), etc.

Comment: Where you have an object (`{...}`) in JSON, you need a class in C#. Where you have an array (`[...]`) in JSON, you need a collection type in C#. What you have in attempt 1 is an object containing an array of arrays of objects. That doesn't match your JSON, which is an array of arrays of objects. With attempt 2 you  have an array of objects, which again doesn't match your JSON. I would expect `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the way the JSON has been designed, your best option is to deserialize it to `List<List<object>>`. There are no properties in the JSON, only object arrays, which I would assume correspond to the properties on your class, but you'll have to do that mapping yourself.

Comment: Your JSON, whilst valid, is not in a very helpful format.    Generally json contains both the field name AND the value, you just have a list of values, so there is no way it will work with #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #1 attempt was nearly there.

You can do:

```
var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(json);
```

but then you will have to do the mapping yourself:

```
var candlesticks =
    from values in arrays
    select new CandleSticks
    {
        openTime = Convert.ToInt64(values[0]),
        open = Convert.ToString(values[1]),
        high = Convert.ToString(values[2]),
        ...
    };
```

I know that most of the values are already in the right format, so at least for the strings you can probably get by with a case, like `high = (string)values[2]`, but for the longs and ints you really want to use `Convert`, since small integer values might become ints and higher values might become longs, and then you can't simply cast.

Comment: thanks for posting - very helpful. how do I access candlesticks? I tried the following but get an error about string not in correct format.
List<CandleStick> candles = candlesticks.ToList();

Comment: Then one of the strings that you try to convert to something is not what you think it is, like you want a long or an int, and instead the json contains a string there.

Comment: thanks again Lasse. i understand what you mean. working too late at night again and my brain has turned to sludge :)

Comment: IMHO serialise as `List<List<JToken>>`, then you just use explicit cast operators https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm.